# Why must a pilot enter "Upwind" when entering the traffic pattern for RWY 9 at Linden (LDJ) airport in New Jersey?

Tags: traffic-pattern, non-towered-airport, airport-operations

The chart supplement procedures require aircraft to enter the traffic pattern "Upwind" for Runway 9 at Linden (LDJ) airport in New Jersey.

**Question: Why is this required?**

**Chart Supplement:**

[image]

---

**New York Terminal Area Chart cutout showing Linden airport:**
[link to chart](http://aeronav.faa.gov/content/aeronav/tac_files/PDFs/New_York_TAC_96_P.pdf)

[image]

**Picture of "Upwind" leg from the Aeronautical Info Manual:**
[image]

Comment: An even more fundamental question, what does "enter upwind" even mean?

Comment: @JScarry - see the description of "Upwind" here: [aim figure 4-3-1](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/media/AIM_Basic_dtd_10-12-17.pdf)

Comment: "Enter upwind" I interpret as approach the airport from the south.  In my experience those kinds of restrictions are usually something to do with noise sensitive areas with bitchy neighbours (the noise abatement procedure and VASI blinders suggest that as well), but I'm not certain enough to post as an answer.

Comment: In this case, the normal 45 degree into the left base for 09 would put you in the 1200/7000 cut out area north of the airport. Getting set up to enter from direction would probably put you near the approaches for traffic landing northeast into Newark. Keeping planes lower and to the south/southeast of Linden would keep planes away from that critical area.  Your drawing also leaves out the 1500 upper limit outside of the loop you do show.

Comment: @CrossRoads- interesting thought.  However, all IFR aircraft going into EWR remain within the lateral and vertical boundaries of the Class B so there should not be a conflict with VFR traffic who are outside of that airspace.  Also, not sure what you mean by the **"normal" 45 degree into the left base for 09** means. Normal entry would be 45 degree to the downwind leg.

Comment: Could someone just call the number listed for Airport Manager and ask, or is that sort of thing really frowned upon?

Answer (score 1):

To keep aircraft away from the multiple obstructions to the east, and also not force people to make their approach from the direction of EWR and mitigate possible conflicts with traffic from that airport.

Comment: One problem with that hypothesis is that by flying upwind, they fly over those obstructions and fly closer to Newark airspace. Another problem is that the TPA is 800' and the floor of the outer shelf starts at 800'. How does that work?  It would make more sense to me to have only left base entries if you want to avoid airspace and obstacles.

Comment: @JScarry- not that it adds a lot of vertical separation, but the floor of the Class B shelf (I think you are referring to) starts above (does not include) 800 ft  That is why there is a "+" sign in front of the 08.  Still pretty thin margins are possible.

Comment: Thin margins is correct.  333, 515, 272 on the ground, and proximity to Newark Airport.  Approaching upwind, crossing, turning downwind at 750 feet would be a pretty good setup for a left turn to base, dropping power, flaps, and speed and holding altitude on the downwind.  Must be quite a circus around there.  Yes, call that airport manager number (and highlight it too).